# Rest best practice, update other ressource when delete other one

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I have 2 ressources:

1- category with 2 fieds: id and name

2- item with : id, name and foreign key of category

In some cases, when i delete a category i can choose to attach related items to an other category.

What is the best practice to do this in Rest ?

1- Can i have delete endpoint on category with path param for id of category to be deleted and a request param containing the new id of category where to attach related items ?

2- Expose a Patch endpoint for item ressource with path param containing set of items ids to be updated with the new category and a body with the new category id to use as foreign key ? And then call the delete endpoint on category ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am agree with your approach. But you can also think about following points:

1. Delete endpoint for category should not accept `new id of category` as a request parameter. If you do so then your API will perform two tasks- first it will delete category and second it will update item objects. And for update operation you should not use `DELETE`.
2. Instead of using delete API to update category id in items your should create a `PATCH` type of API.
3. While creating `PATCH` kind of API, do not provide list of item ids as a path variable. You should use request body to perform this operation. I think you should create a bulk update API for your `item` resource.

You can refer below examples for delete and patch API:

## Delete category API

```
DELETE /api/v1/categories/{categoryId}
```

This API will return `200 OK` if category got deleted successfully. If category is already removed or not present then your API should return `404 NOT FOUND`.

## Bulk update API for items

```
PATCH /api/v1/items
```

Request body for above endpoint

```
[
    {
        "itemId" : 1,
        "categoryId" : 1
    },
    {
        "itemId" : 2,
        "categoryId" : 1
    }
]
```

This API can return `202 ACCEPTED` if you wish to perform your update operation `asynchronously` else you can return `200 OK`.

#### OR

As `PATCH` method may have side effects on other resources; i.e., new resources may be created, or existing ones modified, by the application of a `PATCH`, you can also create below endpoint.

```
PATCH /api/v1/categories/{categoryId}/item
```

Request body for above endpoint to accept multiple item ids:

```
[
    1, 2, 3, 4
]
```

This API can return `202 ACCEPTED` if you wish to perform your update operation `asynchronously` else you can return `200 OK`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @pcsutar, I think I will use the first Patch methode